# Python, check strings for values and remove other characters

Tags: python, ros

```
f= open("new_sample.txt","r")

for ranges_in_file in f:
if(ranges_in_file.find('ranges:')!= -1):
    new_data = ranges_in_file.split(" ")
    print('success')
```

hi guys, currently i am reading a .txt file line by line to find for a certain value. I am able to find the line. For example, `ranges: [1.3,1.9,2.05,inf,1.64]` How do i store the certain line into a list and after that, remove any excess characters in the line such as the word `"ranges"` and `"inf"`?

Comment: do you want the line as a list of values, or do you want a list of lines, as strings, but without the excess words? Could you specifiy your desired output with an example?

Comment: Hi flob, my desired output will be able to read just the values (1.3,1.9,2.05,1.64) and generate a data structure, like a graph or some sort

Answer (score 0):

Given you have read the lines of a file and can get a list,

which is like

```
ranges_in_file = [1.3,1.9,2.05,math.inf,1.64]
```

you can make a comprehension over the things you need/do not need:

```
wanted = [x for x in ranges_in_file if x not in [math.inf, "range"] ]
```

Comment: i think the question is how to get to that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the variable`ranges` and the list using `a,b=ranges_in_file.split('=')` 
`b.strip()`
So b contains your required list as a string. Use `c=list(b[1:len(b)-1].split(','))` to convert it into list. Then you can iterate over list and discard any values you don't want. (Remember now all entries of list are strings!)

Answer (score 0):

If your lines always look like this, so the start with `"ranges: "`, followed by a list of values, and the only thing you want to remove is `inf`, you can turn it into a list of floats easily using a `map`function like this:

```
line = "ranges: [1.3,1.9,2.05,inf,1.64]"
values = list(map(float, [x.strip('[]') for x in (line.split(' ')[1]).split(',') if 'inf' not in x]))
```

Output:

```
[1.3, 1.9, 2.05, 1.64]  # list of float values
```

You can then apply this to every line of the file that starts with `'ranges:'`, which will give you a list of the individual lines value lists. Notice the use of `with open(...`, which is safer to use for files in general, because the file will always be closed properly no matter what happens.

```
values = []
with open('new_sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('ranges:'):
            line_values = list(map(float, [x.strip #.... and so on, see above
            values.append(line_values)
```

But if your lines can be different, a more general approach is needed.

Comment: Hi flob, in my new_sample.txt there are other char and values. However, the ranges: [1.3,1.9,2.05,inf,1.64] will always look like that, just with different values. And the value in ranges: is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

For **new_sample.txt**:

```
 ranges: [1.3,1.9,2.05,inf,1.64]
```

you can split data with delimiter **space** and **", "**:

```
f = open("new_sample.txt", "r")
file = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
result = []

for i in file:
    b = i.split(" ")
    if b[0] == "ranges:":
        temp = b[1][1:-1].split(",")

for j in temp:
    if j not in ["inf"]:
        result.append(j)

print(result)
OUTPUT: ['1.3', '1.9', '2.05', '1.64']
```